# Can't install ubuntu along windows 7

Tags: 12.04, windows

I boot from a DVD the last version of ubuntu 12.04 x64(because i have 8g. of ram) ,hit install Ubuntu ,check Install Along windwos 7(or something like this ,anyway the first option) and the button in the bottom right corner says "Restart to install" or just restart...i cant remember.
So ,i hit the button than ,the screen goes black ,some proceses are stopped and on the middle of the screen it writes like this " Please remove installation media and close the tray (if any) then press ENTER: "

The DVD rom opens and i remove the dvd ,close the tray ,pushing enter and the windows is starting ,no instalation ,no file copied to my PC ,nothing.

Comment: are you sure no file is copied? check the disk usage ? type `diskmgmt.msc` in run prompt and press enter to see the details

Answer (score 0):

I been messing with it all day too and I have problems with the Ubuntu Download link on their home page. I tried unsuccessfully to boot from a live USB and tried burning the iso image to CD, and it said something like that the iso image was not valid or something like that.  I choose the latter option and downloaded a image from the Bitttorrent link also in the Ubuntu website that I had better luck installing a dual boot machine with win 7 and ubuntu 12.04 today.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Ubuntu DVD is corrupt or somehow broken. Verify by using a different Ubuntu ISO.

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: Follow this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM/#MD5SUM_on_Windows

Comment: So...why use a different ISO?